# Should last node of linkedlist be stored for a singly linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

I am preparing for interviews, and for all linkedlist questions I intend to follow Linkedlist.java

I have not seen any sample interview solutions which also store 'lastnode' and 'size' Instead they loop over. I see nothing wrong if in OO, I save last node and size. This would prevent an additional loop to find linkedlist length etc. With your experience do you think interviewer would mind this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about others, but I have never seen storage of last node and size, and I don't really think it's good practice, although it depends on the application.

For an interview though, I would assume that they're looking more for your understanding of the linked list data structure and which algorithms you use to implement the common add/remove/size/etc. functions. I would stray from worrying about specific storage, and focus more on making sure you really understand how a linked list works.